# Python - How to insert data into a mySQL table when the data is stored in a variable?

Tags: python

How to insert data into a mySQL table when the data is stored in a variable?

I have lots of data that will be stored in variables and wish for it to be inserted into the database table.

Comment: Can you provide an [mcve] of what you have so far?

Comment: You'll need a python package that can connect to the DBMS you're using. `psycopg2` is the one for postgresql and reading examples of using that should give you an idea.

Comment: what variable you are talk is it a dict an int or string etc. are you inserting a row

Comment: just a string but it needs to specific which column it is going down

Answer (score 0):

Without any more details, The simple generic answer is: print/format your variable into the query string that you'll be executing on a database. Example:

```
sql_string = "INSERT INTO table_name VALUES('%s', '%s')" % (python_var1, python_var2)
```

or

```
sql_string = "INSERT INTO table_name VALUES('{}','{}')".format(python_var1, python_var2)
```

then execute that on your db. Exact query obviously needs to match your DB schema

Comment: Yeah that makes sense as an answer for me however how do you specific say which column to put the bits of data in?

Answer (score 0):

cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO device (name, MODEL, MEMORY, COLOUR, PRICE, PRICE_UP, PRICE_DOWN, PRICE_DIFF) VALUES (r{0}, r{1}, r{2}, r{3}, r{4}, r{5}, r{6}, r{7})""".format(*device_data))